# Calculate the probability that James' total commute is less than 25 minutes.

Tags: probability

James commutes to work by walking 5 minutes to the bus stop, then waits $X$ minutes for the bus to arrive, after which the bus journey to work takes $Y$ minutes. Supopse $X$ and $Y$ are well-approximated by normal distribution, such that we may assume $X\sim N(4,1)$, and $Y\sim N(20,4)$ with $X$ and $Y$ being independent random variables.

Calculate the probability that James' total commute is less than 25 minutes.

My attempt:

$P(\text{ total commute } < 25)$

$=P(5+X+Y<25) = P(X+Y<20)$

We know that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Hence $Z=X+Y\sim N(20+4,1+4)=N(24,5)$. We also note that $Z>0$ since we can't have negative time.

Hence $$P(Z<20)=\int^{20}_0 f_Z(z)\mathrm{dz}=\int^{20}_0\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(5)\pi}}\frac{e^{-(z-24)^2}}{2(5)}\mathrm{dz}$$

Is this the right way to do this problem? I can't calculate this integral so I think it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. As you wrote,

$$X+Y\sim N(24;5)$$

Thus

$$\mathbb{P}[X+Y<20]=\mathbb{P}\left[Z<\frac{20-24}{\sqrt{5}}  \right]=\Phi\left( \frac{-4}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\approx 3.68\%$$

---

you cannot have a negative time because the range of your gaussian is

$$(X+Y)\in 24\pm 6.71$$

where $6.71=3\sigma$

Comment: Where did you get $\mathbb{P}\left[Z<\frac{20-24}{\sqrt{5}}  \right]$ from? Also, is the expression after that supposed to be the cumulative density function?

Comment: @user: Just standardized your gaussian $W\sim N(24;5)$ so that $\frac{W-24}{\sqrt{5}}\sim N(0;1)$. Yes, $\Phi$ is the CDF of a Standard Gaussian

Comment: @user : Use $Z$ for the standard gaussian...it is not mandatory but usually people do that